# Who is this old man?

Tags: riddle

The little old man has twelve children: some short, some long, some cold, some hot.

Who is he?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a year that's ending. 12 months, some months are short, some are long, some are cold, some are hot.

Comment: How is that a **little** old man?

Comment: and why is he **old**?

Comment: @warspyking He is old because it is ending, right. And, as he is ending, it is becoming smaller and smaller (the less and less time to its end).

Comment: Please read the above comment, @klm123.

Comment: @nicael You could quite easily argue that the year gets bigger as it goes on. Right now, 2014 is just 10 months "big", soon it will be 12 months "big". That feels more intuitive to me than saying it's 2 months "big" right now

Comment: I agree with @Joe's reasoning.

Comment: I think it comes down to a cultural perception of time, especially during the new year. At that time, there are many depictions of a (little) old man handing off the year to a baby.

Comment: @nicael but a year that's ending still has all 12 months,and thus is no more little than when it started; otherwise there aren't any hot months. It's still old because it's been around for nearly its entire life time.

Answer (score 5):

You accepted an answer, but it doesnt answer the question you asked:  Who is the old man?  Its Father Time.

Comment: "Who is *this* old man?"